# Get Hierarchy from XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml, extension-methods, hierarchy

I have an xml structure like this:

```
<Plugin Name="Test">
        <Configuration>
            <Parameter Name="Dummy" Value="1">
                <Parameter Name="Test11" Value="2"/>
                <Parameter Name="Test12" Value="4"/>
                <Parameter Name="Test12" Value="6"/>
            </Parameter>
        </Configuration>
</Plugin>
```

and I have a configuration class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class PluginConfiguration
{
    [XmlElement("Parameter")]
    public virtual List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

now I want to write extension methods for my PluginConfiguration class like this:

```
con.GetValue("Dummy");
```

this should return 1
and

```
con.GetValue("Dummy/Test11");
```

this should return 2
and

```
con.GetValues("Dummy/Test12");
```

should return collection of [4,6]

here is my code:

```
public object GetValue(string arg1)
    {
        arg1 = "Dummy/Test11";           
        string[] splittedArg = arg1.Split('/');

        if (splittedArg.Length == 0) return "";

        string firstParamName = splittedArg[0];
        string lastParamName = splittedArg[splittedArg.Length - 1];
        
        foreach (Parameter param in pluginConfiguration.Parameters)
        {
            if (param.Name == firstParamName)
            {
                if (splittedArg.Length == 1)
                {
                    return param.Value;
                }
                foreach (Parameter param1 in param.Parameters)
                {
                    if (param1.Name == lastParamName)
                    {
                        return param1.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? show us some code

Comment: Imho if you intend to query your data with an XPath-like syntax you should probably leave your data serialized. Else you should look into query using Linq.

Comment: Are you stuck to XML? If not try json

Comment: @JarneKompier yes this should be like this structure

Comment: If the Dummy parameter has 3 sub-parameters, how is its value 1 then? It's like asking for a car but getting the chassis only. Why do you want to query for Dummy just by "Dummy" (without the plugin name) but you query for Test11 by "Test/Test11" (with the plugin name but without the superior "Dummy")? This does not make sense to me. Any why not use pure XPath instead of writing your own syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<string> GetValue(string arg1)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg1))
        return null;

    arg1 = "Dummy/Test11";           
    var splittedArg = arg1.Split('/');

    var firstParamName = splittedArg.FirstOrDefault();
    var lastParamName = splittedArg.Count() > 1 ? splittedArg.LastOrDefault() : null;

    var firstLevelParameters = pluginConfiguration.Parameters.Where(p=>p.Name == firstParamName);

    var returnList = new List<string>();
    
    foreach (Parameter param in firstLevelParameters)
    {
         if (lastParamName == null)
         {
              returnList.Add(param.Value);
         }
         else
         {
              foreach (var subParam in param.Parameters.Where(x=>x.Name == lastParamName))
              {
                   returnList.Add(subParam.Value);
                   //probably would make more sense to add the first level value as well 
                   //returnList.Add($"{param.Value}/{subParam.Value}");
                   //
                   //in your case this would be "1/2"
              }
         }
    
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: This almost done the job, How to make this as an extension method to PluginConfiguration class?

Comment: Not sure what you want to archive.
If you really want to make this as an extension method try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

But if you only want to call this method for each PluginConfiguration, just add this method inside your PC class and call it like 
var pc = new PluginConfiguration(); // Or do your Deserialization
var paraList = pc.GetValue(args);